# Rails: Rendering with Pagination Issues of a Comment Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, pagination

The current page that I have been working on is a page where a user can create a comment under a specific micropost. All the microposts are shown on the same page and those microposts are paginated. Under each specific micropost, there are comments and those comments should be paginated and the issue I am currently having is that the pagination only happens when the HTML code is this:

**HTML**

```
<div id='comments'>
<%=render @comments %>
<%= will_paginate @comments, :class =>"pagination" %>
</div>
```

But the thing is when it is like that only the comments for the first micropost will show up on every single micropost rather than the specific micropost comments. So I figured why not put the code like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id='comments'>
<%=render micropost.comments %>
<%= will_paginate @comments, :class =>"pagination" %>
</div>
```

This basically set all the specific comments in the right micropost BUT it didn't paginate but the pagination links showed, so I figured putting this would work but it didn't, got an error:

**HTML**

```
<div id='comments'>
<%=render micropost.comments %>
<%= will_paginate micropost.comments, :class =>"pagination" %>
</div>
```

I am very confused and unsure what to do and yes the micropost is suppose to have no `@`
I would appreicate any suggestions that would help! Thank you!

My User#Show

**User Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @school = School.find(params[:id])
    @micropost = Micropost.new
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comment = @micropost.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comments = @micropost.comments.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, but the fact that you need to do an assignment inside your view tells you this is probably not the way to do it:

```
<div id='comments'>
  <% comments = micropost.comments.paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page]) %>
  <%= render comments %>
  <%= will_paginate comments, :class =>"pagination" %>
</div>
```

Do realize that the micropost & comments both use the same page parameter. So that if you want to view the second page of comments of any of the given microposts you will also switch to the second page of microposts. I would reconsider showing all this information on the same page.

Comment: mmm I am trying to create a facebook like feed that is why I am trying to find a way to show both on the same page. I am unsure if I am doing this the wrong way or not but it has worked to a certain point.

Comment: also the code that you provided has done the same thing has the second HTML I have posted above, the code is showing all the specific comments on the micropost but doesn't paginate although the pagination links are there according to the specific comments

Comment: that worked :) thank you! May I ask this question of can I ajax that pagination link so it just loads more onto the page?

Comment: Yes you can. Just make a route/controller to something like /microblog/:id/comments.json and process the response via javascript.

Comment: The only thing that is confusing is how can I link the pagination links to a route such as that? mmm and I would do something like `  match "/microposts/:id/comments" => "micropost#(what would I put in here or is this method wrong?)"`

Comment: I think [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources) should get you started.